# Invalid variance: The type parameter must be invariantly valid but is covariant

Tags: c#, generics, asynchronous, covariance

What is wrong with this?

```
// does not compile
interface IRepository<out T>
{
    Task<T> Get(int id);
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on ... 'T' is covariant.
```

However, when I remove the Task, the code compiles:

```
// compiles
interface IRepository<out T>
{
    T Get(int id);
}
```

Why would making an interface asynchronous cause it to not compile?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the `Get` method isn't covariant in its return type, because `Task<T>`, being a class, is not covariant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Asad mentioned above, `Task<T>` cannot be covariant because it is a **class**.  The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) states:

> Only **interface types** and **delegate types** can have variant type
>   parameters.

If only there was a covariant `ITask<T>` **interface**.

After some googling, I found this suggested at [visualstudio.uservoice.com](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5754247-make-task-t-implement-covariant-interface-itask-o).  In the comments, Jeffrey Morse links to his [implementation of `ITask<T>`](https://github.com/jam40jeff/ITask).

Nice work Jeff!